# DBT version 1.7.9 not able to install depedency packages

Tags: python, dbt

I am not able to install dbt-core=1.7.9
facing issue after
Successfully built logbook minimal-snowplow-tracker

then shows this message::

Installing collected packages: text-unidecode, pytz, pytimeparse, parsedatetime, logbook, leather, zipp, urllib3, typing-extensions, sqlparse, six, rpds-py, pyyaml, python-slugify, pycparser, protobuf, pathspec, packaging, networkx, msgpack, more-itertools, MarkupSafe, idna, dbt-extractor, colorama, charset-normalizer, certifi, Babel, attrs, annotated-types, requests, referencing, python-dateutil, pydantic-core, mashumaro, Jinja2, isodate, importlib-metadata, click, cffi, pydantic, minimal-snowplow-tracker, jsonschema-specifications, agate, jsonschema, dbt-semantic-interfaces, dbt-core
Successfully installed Babel-2.14.0 Jinja2-3.1.3 MarkupSafe-2.1.5 agate-1.7.1 annotated-types-0.6.0 attrs-23.2.0 certifi-2024.2.2 cffi-1.16.0 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 click-8.1.7 colorama-0.4.6 dbt-core-1.7.9 dbt-extractor-0.5.1 dbt-semantic-interfaces-0.4.4 idna-3.6 importlib-metadata-6.11.0 isodate-0.6.1 jsonschema-4.21.1 jsonschema-specifications-2023.12.1 leather-0.4.0 logbook-1.5.3 mashumaro-3.12 minimal-snowplow-tracker-0.0.2 more-itertools-10.2.0 msgpack-1.0.8 networkx-3.2.1 packaging-24.0 parsedatetime-2.6 pathspec-0.11.2 protobuf-5.26.1 pycparser-2.21 pydantic-2.6.4 pydantic-core-2.16.3 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 python-slugify-8.0.4 pytimeparse-1.1.8 pytz-2024.1 pyyaml-6.0.1 referencing-0.34.0 requests-2.31.0 rpds-py-0.18.0 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.4 text-unidecode-1.3 typing-extensions-4.10.0 urllib3-1.26.18 zipp-3.18.1

and it come of installation process without installing it

checked for dbt installed
dbt : The term 'dbt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.